# Recorrer un checkbox para una consulta a Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bucles

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy realizando un minimodulo de reimpresión de etiquetas, es decir, el usuario ya genero etiquetas y esas mismas las imprime, yo almaceno los datos en una tabla para posteriormente por X o Y razón debe imprimir nuevamente esas etiquetas (se le rompieron, se le perdieron,etc.) asi que tomo la información ya almacenada de mi BD, el usuario puede escoger el paquete de etiquetas que quiere reimprimir (lógicamente este debe estar en la tabla que ya les mencione) este paquete a su vez contiene una secuencia dependiendo de la cantidad de etiquetas que tenga, es decir estoy generando mis checkbox dinamicamente ya que no puedo saber que cantidad de paquetes tiene cada uno, en este checkbox al seleccionarlo mando la secuencia para que sea mas fácil para mi hacer la consulta, lo antes mencionado ya lo hice en mi controlador ya me llegan los datos seleccionados, es decir si seleccione el primero y ultimo así me llegan, el problema esta en que quiero ahora hacer mi consulta con ese mismo dato, he ido paso a paso desde que me llega la información y la leo con dd() y me la muestra bien pero cuando leo mi consulta con dd()  y seleccione mas de 1 valor solo me devuelve el primero y no ambos, lo leí con var_dump() y me lo devuelve como yo creo que es correcto pero cuando ya lo mando a mi vista solo me devuelve el ultimo que seleccione. No entiendo que pasa si me falta algo o que, les adjunto mis pantallas y código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**la secuencia de paquetes es lo que envió pero solo el numero encerrado en rojo**
Como vieron seleccione el 2 y 3 pero solo me devuelve el 3.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les muestro mi controlador:

```
public function packages(Request $request){
    $checkboxvar=$request->checkboxvar;
    $mono = $request->mono;
    $lineitem = $request->lineitem;
    $pn = $request->pn;

    $cuantos = count($checkboxvar);

    for($a=0;$a<$cuantos;$a++){
        $posicion = $checkboxvar[$a]; //almacene asi la posicion porque sino me dice mysql que hay error de sintaxis

        $etiquetas = DB::select("select IDBULTO,mono,Line,PN,PCSPKG,sequency,Operation,NumPacks,tiempo,WC,idDetalle,OPNSEQ
        from detailBults
        where mono=$mono and Line=$lineitem and PN='$pn' and sequency=$posicion");

    }
```